# Segue error "Ambigious Reference to member 'tableView' " Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

I keep getting this error in the prepare for segue function when i want to add a segue to my View Controller.This is the error : **"Ambigious Reference to member 'tableView' "**

Here's my Code:

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showCountryDetails" {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
    let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as!
    DetailViewController
    destinationController.countryImage = self.photos[indexPath.row]
    } }
}
```

**TravelTableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TravelTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var countries = ["Qatar","Brazil","United Kindgom","KSA"]
    var cities = ["Doha","Rio","London","Riyadh"]
    var photos = ["Qatar.jpg","Rio.jpg","Lndn.jpg","KSA.png"]

    var countryIsVisited = [Bool](count: 4, repeatedValue: false)
    var countryIsNotVisited = [Bool](count: 4, repeatedValue: false)




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countries.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as!TravelTableViewCell

        cell.CityLabel.text  = cities[indexPath.row]
        cell.CountryLabel.text = countries[indexPath.row]
        cell.ImageLabel.image = UIImage(named: photos[indexPath.row])

        cell.ImageLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cell.ImageLabel.frame.size.width / 2
        cell.ImageLabel.clipsToBounds = true

        if countryIsVisited[indexPath.row] {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }

        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "What do you want to do ?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(optionMenu,animated: true, completion: nil)


        let callActionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Service Unavailable", message: "Sorry the phone is not avilable at the mometn", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call " + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style:
                UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: callActionHandler)
        optionMenu.addAction(callAction)

        let isVisitedAction = UIAlertAction(title: "I've been here", style: .Default, handler: {
                (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

                let checkImage = UIImage(named: "Hearts-48.png")
                let checkMark = UIImageView(image: checkImage)
                cell?.accessoryView = checkMark
                self.countryIsVisited[indexPath.row] = true
                })
        optionMenu.addAction(isVisitedAction)

        let isNotVisitedAction = UIAlertAction(title: "I haven't been here", style: .Default, handler: {
            (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            cell?.accessoryView = .None
            self.countryIsNotVisited[indexPath.row] = true
        })
        optionMenu.addAction(isNotVisitedAction)





    }





    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title:
            "Share", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in


            let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Share using",
                preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
            let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Twitter", style:
                UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            let facebookAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style:
                UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            let emailAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Email", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: nil)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
                handler: nil)
            shareMenu.addAction(twitterAction)
            shareMenu.addAction(facebookAction)
            shareMenu.addAction(emailAction)
            shareMenu.addAction(cancelAction)



            self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } )
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default,
                title: "Delete",handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
                // Delete the row from the data source
                    self.countries.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                    self.cities.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                    self.photos.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

                    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)



                } )


        //Adding Background Color to the Delete and Share Button
        shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 166.0/255.0, blue:
                    51.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 51.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue:
                    51.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)


        return [deleteAction, shareAction]


    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "showRestaurantDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as!
        DetailViewController
        destinationController.countryImage = self.photos[indexPath.row]
        } }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Have you taken outlet of `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your connection Outlet to your `tableView`?
Seems your code doesn't have it.
Control-Drag from Storyboard (if you're using them) and your error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

`indexPathForSelectedRow` is a property not a method, remove the parentheses

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
```

Comment: Seem the error didn't go away even after removing the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Just change `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController` in your class definition.

This will make the self.tableView available